# Persisting an environment variable on Solaris

Tags: unix, environment-variables, solaris

I need to change an environment variable $NLS_LANG for Oracle encoding configurations.
I followed the steps:

1. Open /etc/profile file.
2. Added "export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9" line into the file

When I tried;

> echo $NLS_LANG

But console printed the older variable, after executing:

> . /etc/profile

Console printed correctly last assigned value of the variable.

Main problem with this situation, when I open a new console, and execute echo command, console still prints the old value of $NLS_LANG variable.

**So, what is the correct way to persist an environment variable on Solaris ?**
Thanks...

ps: Solaris version is -> 5.10.

Comment: Unless you have a more specific file exporting that I think you just need to logout and login again.

Comment: What shell are you using?   If it's /bin/sh on Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10), then `export VARIABLE=value` isn't supported, you need to use `VARIABLE=value; export VARIABLE`.   The export `VARIABLE=value` syntax works in ksh, bash, and (since it's ksh93) /bin/sh on Solaris 11 & later.

Comment: @alanc I'm using ksh.

Comment: @cnicutar Login/logout process may work but since other developers are using the system, so I hadn't try it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.profile`  is only read by a login shell. Thus, you have to start your shell with a `-`  as first argument to force a login shell (or, as @cnicutar suggested, logout/login).

As an alternative, you can put your assignment into a file that is read at "normal" (interactive) invocation, e.g., `.kshrc` in case of a Korn Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in `/etc/profile` are loaded when you log in with the user. Hence, if you do not log out and log in again the `$NLS_LANG` will not be loaded.

If you do not want to logon now, What you can do is use `EXPORT` to make the system load the new value:

```
NLS_LANG="new value"
export $NLS_LANG
```

or directly

```
export NLS_LANG="new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the export your `.profile` file in your home directory. Please use 
`export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9` in your `/home/folder/.profile` file. this way everytime you logon, the variable will be configured.